# How to download this source code file?

Tags: android, svn, android-source

[Android Translate Application](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FTranslate)

How can I download all file in this trunk link?
Can I load it into eclipse IDE, Windows7 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the instructions on the other tab:

[checkout](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/checkout)

how to get this into eclipse:

- download an svn client from http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html
- read its manual on how to do a checkout.
- checkout as explained on [the checkout tab](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/checkout), using your client and the supplied url.
- import it into eclipse as per the eclipse manual.

Comment: Sure, if you want you can use the svn plugin for eclipse (subclipse: http://subclipse.tigris.org// ). But you might be better off just downloading it trough a 'random' svn client, and then importing it into eclipse, as you just want the code, not the complete svn connection

Comment: Could you recommend svn client? I using Windows7-64bit

Comment: Just pick one from the list I provided. This looks good, but I have no experience: http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download

Comment: Thank you, I can run Translate Project via eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

See the checkout tab on that webpage; it tells you:

> svn checkout http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ apps-for-android-read-only

Which means you need to install subversion for your operating system and run the above from a command prompt/shell.

Comment: I am using Windows7 64-bit, How can I get this code? Can I load it via Eclipse?

Comment: Get the subversion packages from this website: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Answer (score 0):

it is an SVN, so type in your terminal :

> svn checkout
>   http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ apps-for-android-read-only